# flyway migrations not found with spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mariadb, flyway

There is a SQL script `V1.0.0_01__Init_from_ddl.sql` in `/src/main/resources/db/migration` which initializes my database.

-> Running **Spring Boot 2.7.6**, this migration script is completely executed without any error.

-> Running **Spring Boot 3.0.0**, it says: `No migrations found. Are your locations set up correctly?`

I have not changed any properties regarding flyway. My database connection (MariaDB 10.6) is fine.

I have tried to rename the file to `V1__Init.sql` or `V1_0_0__Init.sql` (any many more tries) without any success.

Any ideas, what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a folder problem:

-> My current folder-structure (file-system) of Spring Boot 2.7.6 project:
`../src/main/resources/db/migration/`

-> My current folder-structure (file-system) of Spring Boot 3.0.0 project:
`../src/main/resources/db.migration/`

After setting the folder structure of the Spring Boot 3.0.0 project to the one of the Spring Boot 2.7.7 project, it works well, even with Spring Boot 3.0.0 :)

So, the problem, was not a spring boot migration problem, just a path problem.

Comment: Do you have reference doc where above path changes are mentioned w.r.t spring boot version. I have checked the flyway, spring boot documentations and spring boot migrations documentation but nowhere able to find this change.

Comment: @KunalVarpe It is NOT a spring boot 3 problem. It was a problem, that occurred while copying my spring boot 2.7 project to my spring boot 3 project.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make the problem clearer

Comment: If the steps here resolve your problem, please accept your own answer instead of editing the title of the question

Comment: Perhaps it is best to specify `spring.flyway.locations` in `application.properties` to avoid situations exactly like this one.

Comment: @cyberbrain I have done. (It takes some time until it is possible ;))